# How do I make this request with Guzzle? Error 405 Method Not Allowed in Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST http://**************:8443/api/v2/cli/mail/call` resulted in a `405 Method Not Allowed` response:   Method not allowed  body{ margin:0; (truncated...) in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}( in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113

Code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false, 
                                 'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']]);

$response = $client->post('http://********:8443/api/v2/cli/mail/call', 
                [GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => 
                    ['--create' => 'user@mail.com', 
                     '-passwd' => 'pwres123', 
                     '-mailbox' => true
                    ],
                'auth' => ['admin', '********']
            ]);


echo $response->getStatusCode();
```

I am trying to make this request:

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" "http://**************:8443/api/v2/cli/mail/call" -d '{ "params": ["--create", "user@mail.com", "-passwd", "pwres123", "-mailbox", "true"]}'
```

Comment: The status code is self explained, you are trying to request something in a wrong way. Is this a POST endpoint?

Comment: Yes, the route accepts only POST, it even makes the command line request and it worked correctly.

Comment: @FábioNunes I could solve it, it returns me a 200.How can I execute the request?

Comment: @MateoAgudelo how did you resolve this? I am getting same issue. POST endpoint exist. it works fine with postman but not with GuzzleHttp